# How to remove ID field while inserting values through CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Well I just started learning spring boot, I work for the moment on a little project inserting Data into Database.

This is understood that "Id" shall be self created since I've include @GeneratedValue method. The problem is Intellij auto assigned property names to my data, which is prevent data entering to the database,i copy also image [image: Intellij auto field]

Due to this auto property assigning act by intellij I'm unable to enter data in to database & getting an error (this is what I understand):

```
 /home/kash/Documents/test/demos/src/main/java/com/example/demos/StudentConfig.java:18:32
 java: constructor Student in class com.example.demos.Student cannot be applied to given 
 types;
 required:  
      java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Integer
 found:    java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,int
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I'm looking for an advise, grateful for the help I copy all the script hereunder.

Student.java

```
 package com.example.demos;

 import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
 import lombok.Getter;
 import lombok.Setter;

 import javax.persistence.*;
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @Entity
 @Table
 public class Student {
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(
       name = "student_sequence",
       sequenceName = "student_sequence",
       allocationSize = 1
  )
  @GeneratedValue(
       strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
       generator = "student_sequence"
 )
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private LocalDate dob;
  private Integer age;
 }
```

StudentRepository.java

```
 package com.example.demos;

 import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 @Repository
 public interface StudentRepository
       extends JpaRepository <Student, Long> {
 }
```

StudentService.java

```
 package com.example.demos;

 import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.time.Month;
 import java.util.List;

 @Service
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

     List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentRepository.findAll();

   } 
   }
```

StudentConfig.java

```
 package com.example.demos;

 import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.util.List;

 import static java.util.Calendar.MAY;

 @Configuration
 public class StudentConfig {
   @Bean
   CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(
        StudentRepository repository){
   
        return args -> {
       
        Student John = new Student(
                "John Doe",
                "john@hotmail.com",
                LocalDate.of(2010, MAY, 19 ),
                11
        );
        Student Haider = new Student(

                "Haider",
                "Haider@hotmail.com",
                LocalDate.of(2024, MAY, 10 ),
                2
        );
        repository.saveAll(
                List.of(John, Haider)
        );


    };
}
```

}